# Where I can submit my feedback about 2018 Developer Survey results?

Tags: discussion, survey-2018

Today I received an email from Stack Overflow in which they said to view [2018 Developer Survey results.](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/)

I just wanted to know if there is any way to to submit my feedback about the survey results, so that I can appreciate the Stack Overflow team's hard work. To me, it is very very good.

I think there might be some people who also want to submit their feedback about the survey.

Comment: team@stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure, but since it is about thousands of people, can we have some convenient way to submit quick feedback

Comment: What could be more convenient than an E-Mail address?

Answer (score 5):

Right here on Meta. The [blog post says](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/13/2018-developer-survey-results-live/):

> Have questions or feedback? [Head on over to Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and use the [survey-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survey-2018) tag.

Comment: Indeed. It's not a good channel for just generic praise or thanks, though. That should be directed at the team privately.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Right. Meta is more for complaints.