# What about non-respondents to diversity questions?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

Last year, the Developer Survey [omitted the very large portion of non-respondents](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367405/1394393) on questions of race/ethnicity, sexual orientation, and gender from their reports. This data again does not appear in [this year's demographics summary](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019&utm_content=launch-blog#demographics).

What are the statistics on non-respondents this year? What are the implications of them on the validity of SO's analysis?

Comment: Until we get official numbers, each plot shows the number of data points for that question, so it looks like `1 - 76,668/88,615 = 13.5%` of people did not respond to the question on Race and Ethnicity and `1 - 86,210/88,615 = 2.7%` of people did not respond to the question on Gender.

Comment: @divibisan Huh. Now that I look at it, the number of  *participants* appears to be down from last year.

Comment: I'm confused as to why the website uses surveys at all, instead of using their own platform to get specific answers to improvements; i.e., it seems like the meta section is a running real-time survey