# Stack Overflow Survey: You're still spending too much time focusing on demographic groups, and not enough time improving site mechanics

Tags: discussion, survey

The new survey is chock full of the usual questions trying to determine which demographic groups (race, age, sex, etc.) I belong to.

Apparently there haven't been any lessons learned from the last demographic debacle.

Stack Overflow was, is, and should forever be free of these kinds of demographic distinctions.  By focusing on any demographic group or issue exclusively, you bring discord to a site that never existed in the first place.

Instead of separating people into demographic groups and attempting to achieve some utopian state of absolute equality, how about improving the onboarding process for new users?  Or getting to know your communities better?

Stack Overflow is a programming website.  The only interest its veteran participants has is helping other people with their software development questions.  We don't care whether those people are black, white, female or Martian, because those personal characteristics are irrelevant.

Comment: In other words, the reason StackOverflow is _so_ successful is that we focus on content, and not the user. So then why do we care about the people?

Comment: the reason they keep doing this is, this is painless for them. One way to stop them doing this is to find a way to make it painful for them. We could feature this post so that broader site audience could have a look and bring on their ideas on how to stop it by making it painful. To get the ball rolling, here is my idea: how about those who dislike it wildly misrepresent their actual demographic features. Gotta break them stats

Comment: @gnat: While I admire your enthusiasm, it's not my intention to start another fight.  I'm merely reminding everyone how we got here.

Comment: this is not enthusiasm but mere realism. They gotta keep doing this until we show them teeth. Keep in mind, here we're we're talking not to reasonable folks from dev / CM team (who managed surveys in the past without this pollution) but to their current overlords from marketing, who only understand things when faced the risk of real losses

Comment: @10Rep maybe for you, but the most dcare about rep and i think a fair amount do care about the people, sometimes it doesn't look that way, and the tone get very rough

Comment: Just do the survey, but don't answer any questions relating to gender, colour or nationality.

Comment: Remember, "On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog".

Comment: @nbk We only rate content, not users. The people that care about users and upvote because it's [so and so] user don't understand why SO exists. But that's not to say that if you recognize a user from elsewhere to not say anything.

Comment: I think the title is bit too "zero sum game" for my tastes. It's not like the developers who would be working on improving site mechanics are spending time making site surveys. They're likely different teams.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: While I do agree that the employees at Stack Overflow are capable of focusing on more than one thing, the ability to do so effectively depends on correctly identifying *what to focus on.*

Comment: I've trimmed a lot of conversations on a tangent to the purpose of the question. Please keep comments focused on the question at hand, and not other subjects. Thanks.

Comment: The "and" in the title could be a bit of a false dichotomy. It gives the impression that both things are related and that may or may not be the case, but I have difficulties seeing that it must be related. Might just be coincidence.

Comment: The root problem has always been that it's so US centred. And so it is focusing on topics that are interesting to hipsters in NY. Not so much to programmers. Particularly not to programmers living outside USA.

Comment: To be fair there are some demographic groups that might actually make sense to know: level of education, years of experience, English proficiency, internet access... . They are all related to programming or the ability to take part on this platform somehow. Maybe the survey also asked about them.

Comment: do you really believe there's a relationship between the number of questions asked on the developer survey and the amount of features that the stack overflow development team can work on?

Comment: I gave up filling out the "survey" a couple of years ago. It's only purpose these days is as propaganda  for SO Inc. They're just looking for headlines for the press to pick up. *1 in 10 developers identify as Martians*, etc.

Comment: People should just learn to enter "Jedi" for any fields like "gender" or "race". Then, eventually, senior staff would have to call themselves "Sith!"

Comment: Seconding Heretic Monkey's view--What is lost by having this information? Since this is about software, you should know that we collect allllll kinds of diagnostics. What is different about this, when compared to collecting device model and OS version data for a mobile app?

Comment: Demographics and emotional manipulation is where the money is.

Comment: "... bring discord to a site that never existed in the first place" I assume you mean "... that never had it in the first place". I mean, of course, the _site_ didn't exist in the first place, but that is not the point, is it? :-)

Comment: @jpmc26 The post is no longer Hot Meta Post. Checking the timeline i see no "Removed from HMP" [tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353492/hot-meta-posts-allow-for-removal-by-moderators-and-thoughts-about-future-impro?cb=1). Is it normal that a post with score +300 is automatically removed from Hot Meta after being there for only 2 days?

Comment: @user Hot posts is kind of random. It's not based on vote total alone (or even primarily). I've seen this question pop on and off the sidebar a few times over the past couple days.

Comment: @AdrianMole - I'd welcome that, I'd imagine it'd turn into a comment in the survey summary about "did you know that a large percentage of our users identify as jedi?" with the powers that be not realising that most of those entries were in protest

Comment: @Sayse How about Race: Peaceful, Gender: Protestor?

Comment: Is the SO survey still biased against VB.NET by apparently denying its existence?

Comment: These surveys don't have anything to do with equality or programming; they're for marketing purposes. From targeted advertising to PR virtue-signaling, it's about profit.

Comment: Why did you delete my comment? I'll post it again. I am actually surprised this post wasn't taken down due to "racism". I'm happy to see this up.

Comment: I would guess that the surveys are a significant part of the way that SE makes money (since they put so much effort into presenting the information, at very least it might give them credibility, e.g., "we understand developers"). I've never heard of survey takers promising to deliberately report wrong information, I find it troubling that I'm starting to see comments suggesting that as a course of action, and I'll be honest, I can't support that initiative. It's just dishonest, I'd personally just not answer that question if I felt that way. Seems like things are getting more and more tense.

Answer (score 123):

The goal of collecting these statistics is to judge people by the color of their skin, the particular genitals they possess, or the gender they state rather than by the content of their character. We know this to be the case because any disparity found in the data is immediately attributed to prejudice, rather than further investigated to see if it correlates to behaviors instead. Any grievance someone attributes to their characteristics is immediately validated by SO staff, whether it holds water or not. "Disadvantaged" or "marginalized" (or in more traditional terminology, "oppressed") groups are instantly judged positively, whether an individual who is a member of that group has produced quality content or not, and those who disagree with this outlook are ostracized irrespective of the character they have demonstrated (e.g. Monica). In short, nothing has changed within SO: it has, as a matter of policy, embraced an ideology that insists people are judged by class and characteristics rather than actions. 2019 demonstrated we can no longer assume good faith on the part of SO.

Comment: Well, SO curators are an oppressed group.  Maybe we should hold a street rally to protest our grievances.  We could throw old database/OS manuals through windows...

Comment: To say what you implied: SO thinks they know the reasons for behaviors and are collecting data to support that thinking.  Instead, they should approach this scientifically and seek the *actual* root cause, whether or not it matches their pre-conceived notions.  When the only data you're collecting lines up with your preconceptions, it's almost impossible to end up with the correct answer.

Comment: Root cause of what exactly? Sounds like a classic case of premature optimization if you will...

Comment: @CameronSima I would say it's a case of trying to optimize for exactly the wrong thing. They're trying to optimize for demographics rather than substance, and they're doing that because of an ideology that insists demographics are more important than substance. Frankly, I find that ideology revolting; it openly promotes being racist and sexist.

Comment: This argument is fantastic can be expanded well beyond SO. If everyone was judged based on their actions and words, and had a lego block for their head, we would stop vilifying those that shouldn't be and stop giving a pass to those that shouldn't have one. We can all agree that no matter your physical makeup if you ask a new question of "How do I print a string to console in Java" then you suck and are lazy

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer doesn't apply to SO. It applies to "modern" society as a whole. It's no longer a matter of who _you_ are and what _you_ have done, the only thing that matters is what group do you belong to. "I have a dream that my four little children will one day live in a nation where they will not be judged by the color of their skin" I agree 100%, unfortunately so many have forgotten about the rest of the sentence: "but by the content of their character."

Comment: @FreeMan Did you mean it doesn't apply *only* to SO? Because if you're suggesting SO somehow avoided this trend, I would contend that it was ahead of the rest of society. (The first sentence of your comment seemed to read that way in isolation, but the rest suggests you meant what I said.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Oh, don't worry, I fully realize that it hit the fan at SO. Unfortunately, that shoulda been "SO`<comma>` `<lowercase>`it...", not "SO`<period>` `<capital>`It..." Typo on my part lead to confusion on your part.

Answer (score 93):

Fundamentally, the nature of a field such as software development, or any kind of software/hardware interaction, is that neither the software nor the hardware *care* about the race, gender, age, or background that their operator is taking part of programming them in.

[Not gonna deny that it'd be *smart* every now and again](https://www.iflscience.com/technology/this-racist-soap-dispenser-reveals-why-diversity-in-tech-is-muchneeded/) to factor those differences in, but the blunt reality is that these cold machines don't care who you are or what you are.  They only function.

Stack Overflow, as a consequence of Q&A, is an attempt to isolate and cut out all of the extra fluff about empathy and ethics, since both of those things are subjective and cannot be **concretely** answered.  We'll have opinions, but opinions aren't **facts**, and Q&A is about **facts**.

Stack Overflow is entirely predicated on the notion of *code* or something that can be explained without knowing anything about the person that's asking it, or where they're from.  In essence, we don't care *by design*; the fact that a person has written a poor question has nothing to do with their background in the slightest.  (Well, maybe a bit on the English comprehension side, but there are legion non-native English speakers who are able to write questions effectively here.)

Surveys and questionnaires are an attempt by Stack Exchange to identify who the people are that are interacting with the machine.  This means that you *do* get questions about your age, gender, and race.  **That makes complete sense.**

The problem that I see with a survey that asks these questions is,

### what *question* are you trying to answer?

This may represent the chief disconnect between staff and the larger Meta Stack Overflow community.

Staff see the users are **people** with diverse backgrounds and walks of life, and value this.
Power users see users as another person with **another coding problem**, with no opportunity or chance for the chit-chat.

Again, that is by design.  I'm not here to play therapist or hear about how oppressive the field is for people of color.  I'm here to answer your technical question, and that's about it.

The problem is that the company [clearly has a different question in mind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354804/175248) when engaging groups of people that use the site, as opposed to the people who are, for lack of a better phrase, left ["holding the bag"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/be-left-holding-the-bag) on content moderation and curation.

Until we agree with the question they're trying to answer, we're ***never*** going to like these surveys.

Comment: There are also several non-English versions of Stack Overflow to cater to those who cannot speak it.

Comment: @jpmc26:  Sure, but neither are they as big as Stack Overflow, nor are they as comprehensive, nor are there all languages to suit.  They stopped doing this multi-lingual Stack Overflow thing a few years ago but I couldn't describe exactly why.

Comment: "Surveys and questionnaires are an attempt by Stack Exchange to identify who the people are that are interacting with the machine. ... That makes complete sense." I don't understand this. Age, I can understand, because it has a strong relationship with a person's experience and maturity. But why does it "make sense" to ask what the color of a person's skin is? In fact, in what manner does a person's skin color tell SO anything meaningful about the person? Isn't it racist to make assumptions about a person's background, walk of life, ability, personality, or other traits from their skin color?

Comment: @jpmc26:  You can make as many assumptions about the demographics of your website if you like.  The idea of gathering data is to *not* make assumptions, anymore.

Comment: @Makoto I would say that asking about a person's race fundamentally assumes that race must be an important factor in something related to this website. Even if we assume the motivation is user retention as your other post suggests, that *requires* assuming race somehow influences factors involved in user retention. But this is a non sequitur unless you are entertaining the idea that race is more than just skin color; it requires assuming that race somehow influences behavior or ability.

Comment: I agree @RobertHarvey.  I don't like the idea of them categorizing us.  I'm only stating that I *get* why they're doing it.

Comment: @jpmc26:  I think you're missing the forest for the trees.  There is a demand for more data about how diverse tech is.  A survey like this is an attempt to get that data.  The only real question that I have to follow up with is, "what is the actual question that Stack Overflow - a site that by its very nature *should* not care about anything besides whether or not a question was answered well - asking?"

Comment: "There is a demand for more data about how diverse tech is." By whom? For what purpose? Is it acceptable for SO to give in to a demand based on assuming race influences behavior or ability? Because that sounds like acquiescing to a racist worldview to me.

Comment: @jpmc26:  By tech leaders.  To showcase that they are actually treating the matter of there being an acute lack of diversity in tech as a serious but correctable problem.  Stack Overflow *absolutely* should be participating in that kind of data gathering, because if you have a lot of predominantly one-race one-gendered people working on a site as wide-spread as this, there is **undoubtedly** some level of bias that creeps in.  Gathering this data gives the company a chance to analyze that bias.

Comment: "...there is undoubtedly some level of bias that creeps in..." Nope. It is not undoubtedly any kind of bias based on race. Undoubtedly some shared cultural values, maybe, but that's not race.

Comment: @jpmc26:  At the education institution I work at, we released a feature that showcased students' photos in our online learning system so that faculty could see who their students were and get to know them better.  The bias in the room that we hadn't accounted on was, what happens if someone is transgender and they consider that identity dead?  It was a sobering moment to us all to realize that we had overlooked this as we scrambled for a way to exclude photos from some students at their request. **There is *always* some level of bias that comes into play.** It doesn't *have* to just be racial.

Comment: Well, with that statement @jpmc26, I don't think there's much else our little sidebar will add to this matter.  I've said my piece and I believe that the focus should be more on the kind of question that Stack Overflow is trying to answer with their engagement efforts, not the engagement effort itself.

Comment: @jpmc26: What's wrong with a school displaying a photo of a former student, now dead? If the school got consent from the student to use the photo, then there is no obligation to take it down.

Comment: @Beta You're misunderstanding. The hypothetical person is still a student with professors looking at the photo, and their appearance is now drastically different as a result of transitioning. Makoto is saying that an old photo is being used to identify a student, and the person considers their self with the other sex "dead." Makoto considers this "bias" because it represents a previous state the person now rejects as part of their past that may influence a professor's initial impression.

Comment: @Beta I find this view strange, though. It's not as though everything that happened before they transitioned is now erased. Their high school credentials likely received under an old name are still recognized, for example. If you believe gender isn't dictated by physical appearance or qualities, then why is it "biased" that a system might contain an out of date photo before your transition? How is updating the photo any different than updating the name? Normally, saying your past is dead to you merely means that you have changed significantly, not that you deny its existence (even in part).

Comment: @jpmc26: No, I did not misunderstand. If the student points to the old photo and says "take that down, that person is *dead",* the administrator can shrug and say "that's not a reason to take a picture down. We have lots of pictures of dead former students and staff on the walls, an plenty of pictures of living people who now find their old pictures embarrassing. People who really dislike their old photos can ask us to remove them, but we won't remove a picture on the chance that someone *might* not like it any more."

Comment: @Beta Ah, I see what you're saying. If they regard their old identity as a separate person who is truly dead, then they forfeit the right to control the old photo. In other words, they can't have it both ways. If they regard their old identity as dead, then the more similar situation would just be that someone entered the wrong photo for them by mistake (even though that isn't exactly what happened), in which case they need only request that the photo be corrected if it's currently used to identify them.

Answer (score 84):

> Instead of separating people into demographic groups and attempting to achieve some utopian state of absolute equality, how about improving the onboarding process for new users? Or getting to know your communities better?

In theory, this information can be used to do both of those things, or at least to do them *better*.

I say "in theory" because after over a year of these surveys we still have very little idea of how the data is being used.

### Positive potential

Here's what you'd want to see: demographic information used to identify biases in some part of the system, features or instructions or checks that disproportionately affect members of some sub-group.

A somewhat-obvious example might be a situation where the automated quality checks trigger on certain phrasings that are a strong predictor of quality issues *for the majority of writers* but a weak predictor for a sub-group with different default writing styles (we ran into this exact problem face-first when we started rolling out International sites, so I would be surprised if it *didn't* exist on the English site as well!).

A more subtle example might involve more indirection: imagine a bias that kept certain groups out of /review, resulting in an emergent bias against a programming language that was disproportionately used by those groups. That sort of thing is *really* hard to tease out, but invaluable if you can identify it!

### Negative potential

OTOH... Do we really need a reminder of [how disastrous poor analysis can be when put to use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343802/what-data-about-meta-has-eluded-stack-exchange-until-recently), especially if built on poor data?

Even with the best of intentions, work done based on incorrect analysis has the potential to actually *hurt* the subgroups being analyzed. Or hurt everyone. Or hurt everyone resulting in blame being laid at the feet of a subgroup that never asked for special treatment.

We've seen *all of this* in the past, and it sure ain't pretty.

### Conclusion: the need for oversight

The potential for good is enormous, but data is never benign once it is being put to use. This is why it is critical to ask questions about how such data is being used: we cannot afford to extend trust or assume good intentions here. I brought up [the failure to report on results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351024/stack-overflow-2020-q12-company-commitments-report-card) repeatedly in the past, but it continues - therefore, I have come to regard these surveys with intense suspicion, as one should always do when an organization is taking pains to obscure how they handle sensitive data.

Let's not treat this as a distraction or a benign effort; this is a serious undertaking with the potential for both great good and great harm.

### Addendum: demographics as a starting point

Came across this talk today by C++ veteran and former SO user ThePhD:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/vaLKm9FE8oo

The first half covers your concerns and the relevance of demographic information. Crucially, it highlights the importance of accurate information, of having a clear hypothesis up front, and of further research dedicated to proving or disproving that hypothesis if demographics give it credence. I can't really do it justice, worth a listen if you have the time.

Comment: "...different default writing styles..." This requires assuming that race influences your writing style. If you want to ask about writing styles, develop questions that identify a person's writing style rather than assuming race has anything to do with it.

Comment: "demographic information used to identify biases in some part of the system" and here is the problem... even if you have all the data identifying the bias may be mission impossible. And SO does not even have the actual data to begin with. Only fraction of users complete surveys, you cannot even be sure they statically correctly represent all users and there is no way to validate whether demographic data they provide is true.

Comment: It's not that we don't talk about the poor analysis job because it's a convenient example of poor analysis Shog; it's that we bring it up often as a reminder that poor analysis is toxic and far more detrimental to one's overarching goals than they realize.

Comment: Race is dubious *as a concept*, @jpmc26; the fact that it *can* correspond to such things in specific contexts comes down to how that concept has been used in the past to divide people and the social/cultural elements that have grown up as a result. IOW, it can still be useful, but you need other information (locale, age, etc) to make use of it.

Comment: Yes, @Dalija - this is a brutally difficult undertaking. All the more reason to make sure it is being done well.

Comment: @Shog9 I would expect that actively grouping people based on race data can do nothing but perpetuate the historical divisions. If you focus instead on the non-racial qualities, you take an active step toward breaking down any artificial divisions.

Comment: Perpetuation isn't a necessary outcome, but it is certainly a *potential* one, @jpmc26. Lest we forget, redlining and worse has been the predominate use of *exactly this sort of demographic data* in the past! That doesn't mean *this* dataset has to be used in such a manner, but it does underline the potential for harm and the need for care and oversight.

Comment: SO no longer demonstrates care or oversight. Their record is simply appalling. Saying they need to use care and oversight is like telling a pyromaniac not to light the box of matches they're holding. SO has actively looked for justifications for advancing class grievances for well over a year now. They need to stay away from this stuff until they show they can be trusted with it.

Comment: I like this answer a lot because is most prominently feature that it's less the data that's a problem and more the conclusions that people draw from it.

Comment: Heh... what I want to say is there is no "done well". There is not even "done better". Thinking that kind of information can help improving anything is merely an illusion. There are many things SO can do to improve the site(s). The best part of SO was always "we don't care who you are, we care about quality of your content, and last but not the least we treat everyone equally". Treating everyone equally can only be achieved if you literally treat everyone equally. The second you start treating someone differently, equality is gone.

Comment: Main problem is onboarding new users. And new users come in all shapes and colors... the only common thing they have is they are new to this site and they are not familiar with the rules.

Comment: Love the report card; I think the judgements in it are reasonably fair.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, @Dalija - but implementing that gets into a lot of details that aren't so easy. When folks talk about "equality", they can mean a lot of different things: equal opportunity, equal treatment, equal effect... For example: if I speak English to an English-speaker, and English to a Japanese-speaker, I'm nominally providing equal treatment - but the effects aren't equal: one person hears their native tongue, another does not. That isn't necessarily *unreasonable*, of course - but, it does have effects, and if you're seeking to understand them then information is useful.

Comment: "*...we ran into this exact problem face-first when we started rolling out International sites*" - that sounds like a really interesting story.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on "default writing styles"? E.g., what would be an example of one?

Comment: Equality has many faces. And even when you try to nominally provide equal treatment, that does not mean that it will be fully unbiased and effects will almost certainly be different depending on the receiver. But, this is unavoidable and as long as we collectively try our best to really treat people equally and without discrimination, I think we are doing fine.

Comment: When it comes to company and trying to understand particular group of users and their needs focusing on broad demographic is wrong approach. It will never yield good results. If there is a particular issue that need to be solved then focus of any survey or any other analysis must be very precise and must deal with that particular problem only, leaving very little room for misinterpretation.

Comment: I'm afraid this is probably true, @dalija; if we look at how the survey is structured and the few reports that *were* posted at the start of the year... It looks an awful lot like it's being used to calculate a loyalty score. IOW, an inscrutable metric without clear or specific meaning that can be used to justify doing - or not doing - whatever its interpreter desires. If true, that's... Not good.

Comment: One of my favorite examples is the space-before-punctuation thing that French writers use at the end of sentences and often carry over into English text, @Peter. A simple thing without any inherent implication apart from native style.

Comment: That is 99% by Indian/Pakistani writers (due to the [very late adoption of *later* editions of the 1935 Wren & Martin textbook](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645))

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm not going to say it's offensive, but it hasn't originated from India. And plus, how is knowing who's Indian and who's not even relevant to SO? It's kind of hurting to me, an Indian with decent grammar, for someone to say that an Indian's english skills are weird and different. I'm an Indian, so I do know this as a fact.

Comment: @Shog9 Also, I agree with most of your answer, except for the part where you say that its useful to collect ethnical data to determine their grammar. As an Indian, I have _decent_ grammar and word usage. Certainly not the most salubrious out there, but better than some people. And if an indian user (or anyone of any other ethnicity) makes a post with poor grammar, one can't assume that it will apply to everyone of that same ethnicity. One might say it's generalizing. Not accusing you of anything, but I just wanted to put my point out there :)

Comment: I don't disagree at all, @10Rep. Demographics can help you understand where you might be failing a given population, but it can't as easily allow you to better serve them (a somewhat benign example that you may have seen involves browsers or websites using demographic heuristics to adjust their display or behavior - I got charged extra for a plane ticket once because the airline mistakenly thought I was in a different country...) One of many reasons why I so stridently urge care and caution with the collection and use of this data.

Comment: Sadly, @Shog9, my phone's keyboard will often put a space before punctuation, even though I've selected US-English. I actually care enough about how I communicate that I'll reread and proof-read my messages (except when I've made a blatant and embarrassing typo, it seems) and fix it, even if it's "just" a message to my wife who is willing to overlook my random typos, or, if she notices them, just laugh. #TIL that there is a cultural reason for this, maybe my keyboard's programmers are all French...

Comment: @10Rep - I've worked with a multitude of Indians, both in-person and offshore. Usually, I can identify an Indian background based on phraseology and word order. There is no way in the world I'd have pegged you as Indian based on that comment! Your grammar is probably better than 50%, nah... 75% of Americans!

Comment: @FreeMan I'm flattered :). And you've actually covered my point! It's impossible to group people into ethnicity based on their level of grammar. I've seen the french stereotypical accent, but that doesn't mean I would say everyone who has different word order is not american.

Comment: @10Rep you're most welcome. There are certain phrases and somewhat awkward word orderings that usually tag someone as a non-native English speaker. Of course, they all speak/write English far, _far_ better than I speak/write their language! A smattering of French, a bit of Hebrew, and I can count to 10 in 4 or 5 other languages, so full marks to all of them!

Comment: "Race is dubious as a concept" - how do you reconcile this assertion with the fact that children of two parents generally deemed to be of the same race, are overwhelmingly deemed to also be of the same race in the same societal context, even by people who don't know who the child's parents are? And that this result persists even when the parents are of different ethnicities, practice different religions etc.?

Comment: I'm gonna say "citation needed", @Karl. In the US, where race has been codified into law in various forms for its entire history, there are loads of examples of folks "changing" their race by just... Moving to a new place and not telling anyone. That tends to be the way with societal constructs: they're only as constraining as the society that imposes them.

Comment: My citation is the fact that people have skin colours, facial geometries, etc. which are strongly genetic and can be visually inspected. That a different culture (and yes, the US contains many different cultures) can have a different folk conception of race that clusters differently, doesn't make race "dubious as a concept", any more than the fact that Japanese people use the word 青 (literally blue) for many things I would consider 緑 (green) makes colour "dubious as a concept".

Answer (score 46):

The demographic data harvested by the survey is patently unfit for any purpose. Even assuming everyone who completed the survey filled in the demographic section absolutely honestly, there's no guarantee that those people are proportionally representative of Stack Overflow's userbase - i.e. the survey suffers from an implicit selection bias.

Which really begs the question why Stack Exchange Inc. continues to insist on collecting this data, especially when they employ a data scientist who (one hopes) would know said data's uselessness. At this point I can't really conceive of a valid and/or benign reason, and since SE Inc. continues to refuse to explain what they are doing or intend to do with this data, it all begins to appear rather ominous.

I would strongly advise everyone to refrain from participating in future surveys until SE Inc. clarifies what they're using this data for. If you do decide to participate, under **absolutely no circumstances** should you provide truthful demographic data - either omit that section entirely, or take creative liberties.

Comment: Do we even know how they choose who to solicit a survey response from? I haven't received a random survey prompt since before the CoC replacement.

Comment: Taking "creative liberties" with that section does create a risk of SE using the data to create policies based on misinformation, while leaving it blank, if possible, just signals SE that we don't wish to provide this data. This is especially tricky if you fill the rest in truthfully, since this might lead to patterns based upon who doesn't want to provide demographic data.

Comment: @ErikA Perhaps purposefully-noisy data will provide the incentive for them to discard the dataset entirely.

Comment: So, the solution to the data being inaccurate is to lie and make it even more inaccurate? Also, do you have a better alternative that would result in more accurate data? The self-selection bias isn't all that easy to avoid (unless you have some means to compel people to participate, which they don't).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you pay attention to Yelp reviews or Amazon.com reviews? Because that - and a whole lot of other things - have self-selection bias too.

Comment: @ErikA They will happily [ignore the fact that people don't wish to provide the information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367405/1394393). It won't be mentioned in their analysis, and it won't be considered in their conclusions.

Comment: If you believe the survey could be unrepresentative and therefore wrong, why interact with the survey at all? Wouldn't the results from the entire survey be potentially misleading, and not just the demographics section?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic comment [right above yours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401807/stack-overflow-survey-youre-still-spending-too-much-time-focusing-on-demograph/401865#comment800643_401843) refers the explanation why simply ignoring the survey (unfortunately) didn't work

Comment: @gnat I think I was not very clear. If someone thinks the survey is invalid because the responders are not proportionally representative of the user base, why is the line drawn with the demographics data? Wouldn't all the non-demographics questions also be irrelevant?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Amazon review scores don't have potentially far-reaching ramifications for privacy, last time I checked.

Answer (score 28):

**TL;DR** Did the Code of Conduct changes work, or are the problems they were supposed to address still there?

I'm going to take a contrary position to what the question is advocating and say that the value of this data really depends on what Stack Exchange does with it. (I don't have much confidence that they will, in fact, do the right thing with it, but I suppose that it's possible).

I would like to point out that some of the groups that they ask about have [indicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334577/343810) that they do, in fact, feel that there's a problem with their demographic being welcomed. For all the uproar caused by the Code of Conduct changes last fall, there's been remarkably little follow-up on whether the changes that were implemented were actually effective at helping these groups. At a minimum, I'd like to know whether the CoC changes helped the situation or whether they still feel that there's a problem. This data could, if interpreted properly, help answer that.

Comment: Not contradictory at all.  What Stack Exchange does with the data is precisely the right question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Fair enough. My point is that there is, in fact, *a* valid use of collecting this data. As to whether they actually do the right thing, I have much less confidence.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Isn't the question kind of implying that there's no valid use for this data at all? Or are you saying that Stack Exchange is almost certain to misuse the data? I don't agree with the first statement, but the second statement seems pretty likely.

Comment: I'm more or less implying that the costs outweigh the benefits.

Comment: With regard to what SO is doing with the information, there seems to be an assumption that if every demographic felt equally welcome, then every demographic would be equally represented; and conversely, that differences in representation imply that certain demographics feel disproportionately unwelcome. The promotion of this idea then leads under-represented demographics to attribute their feeling of being unwelcome to some type of discrimination, when in fact it's simply how all newcomers feel.

Comment: The data has no demonstated veracity.  Unless a meet-greet and private investigation is undertaken, there is no way to judge the accuracy of the data. Yes, some people lie on the internet, grrrrrr....WOOF!

Comment: If I can get all my work done, or lash out against those who refused to do it all for free, why not claim that my coat is chocolate instead of golden?

Comment: I'd argue that the changes were effective alright. If the goal was to drive users providing answers away from the site, that is. https://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/how_sjws_affected_stack_overflow.shtml

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers That's only "effective" if that's what they were trying to achieve (which they weren't). That's why it's so important to get metrics around whether or not the changes had their intended effect, and whether there were also some unintended effects. For example, if the marginalized groups that were supposed to be helped by the changes still feel just as marginalized as they did before, then clearly they didn't help. If people are more reluctant to answer because of the new CoC, that's clearly an unintended effect. We need to understand what the actual effects were.

Comment: *"That's only "effective" if that's what they were trying to achieve (which they weren't)."* Please readjust your sarcasm detectors. *"If people are more reluctant to answer because of the new CoC, that's clearly an unintended effect."* People getting pissed off by the CoC and how corporate handled it, and as a result leaving for good (like myself), is a far more likely reason than people just getting "more reluctant to answer."

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I'd say driving away the user base was exactly the goal. Programming skill correlates strongly with attitudes they consider toxic, such as objectivity and rationality. They're perfectly willing to trade competence for diversity, consequences for the industry and the economy be damned. This mirrors the rapid collapse of competence at companies like Microsoft and Google around 2005, which was a direct result of making diversity a goal rather than making equal opportunity the goal and diversity proportional to interest the metric.

Comment: @StackOverthrow Importantly, the idea that even opportunity results in even demographics emphatically does *not* appear to be the case. [Thomas Sowell on the subject over 40 years ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y021WAdUlW8), modern research in gender differences [1](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0956797617741719?journalCode=pssa&), [2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0191886917305962?via%3Dihub)

Comment: @StackOverthrow I don't know how you could reliably measure preferences, though. Not to mention that preferences could shift over time, and they will vary by culture (even regional culture or even rural vs. suburban vs. city culture). I would expect that to be an intractable problem. Also people may have preferences that don't match their abilities.

Comment: @jpmc26 But that doesn't mean that we shouldn't try to create equal opportunity for everyone. As I pointed out in my answer, several demographics feel that that isn't the case. That's a problem whether it's true or not, too; even if it isn't true, the perception that it's true will have the same effect as it actually being true.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica That they feel it isn't the case doesn't mean that it isn't. The effect is not the same if their perception is wrong. If their perception is wrong, that means the appropriate action is for leaders to back the community and promote the truth. SO instead asserted that their feelings trump the truth and consequently blamed the community, and they focused their efforts on that basis.

Comment: FYI, the website that Ansgar Wiechers points to in his comment is basically his own personal blog. The article is his and he completely ignores the +40 million lost jobs as the reason for the 2nd dip in Answer, even though it corresponds nearly identically to the slope and timing of that 2nd slope.

Comment: *"the website that Ansgar Wiechers points to in his comment is basically his own personal blog."* Given that my name is in the contact info I doubt that people needed you to point that out. Also, please explain how layoffs in March/April would a) cause a steady decline of the answer rate since the beginning of January, and b) have an impact beyond the downward spike I already discounted for, when the [vast majority of lost jobs](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/05/08/these-industries-suffered-the-biggest-job-losses-in-april-2020.html) are unlikely to be SO users in the first place.

Comment: *\*crickets\** Figures.

Answer (score -5):

I'm very confused why this is an issue:

1. Adding a few demographic trackers to a survey doesn't take any "time", it's literally a small handful of checkboxes
2. Tracking demographic information is a normal and important part of any community, especially one where the results are so skewed

Direct benefits of tracking demographics:

- Detecting declines in certain groups could be a sign of discrimination or other issues in the community
- Making sure that SO's demographics at least match up with overall demographics
- Research and study by others

It is no secret that computing fields are not diverse. Is SO the sole reason for these disparities? Probably not. But does it contribute? I think the answer is definitely yes. Take for example this (top rated, accepted) answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367555/4204557

It quotes *Thomas Sowell* of all people, a person who has routinely discredited BLM, among many other things. On top of that, it uses a quote from 40 years ago (a very racist time indeed) where he claims that statistics are not proof of discrimination, a strawman used by many white supremacists. In the comments there is the infamous Morgan Freeman quote on racism ("Stop talking about it"), which is all but trying to deny the existence of racism.

In the answer *right under that*, also positively rated, the issue of demographic disparity is brought up, to which it claims that it is not a real issue and that we should just ignore it because disparities exist in other fields as well. Aside from that fact that this is hilariously wrong (computing related fields used to be 50/50 split male/female) it is very clearly not welcoming to say, another female user on the site (I confirmed this with my wife).

I don't need to question whether these are harmful: I know they are. I can ask many people that I know who are minorities whether this is welcoming or not, and they will clearly say no. As a minority myself I can confidently say this is not welcoming. As a community we simply have to acknowledge that this is an issue we need to work on. It is really not that hard to do so.

Comment: I know I'm late, but read me: it's irrelevant to know how many colored people code, okay? It's irrelevant to SO.

Comment: Just because you said it does not make it so. Maybe provide some reasoning as well?

Comment: Because SO only exists to provide an encyclopedia for programmers. It doesn't matter how many colored people contribute to SO, or how many white people contribute. The knowledge stays the same. Maybe in the outside world it might matter, but in SO: It doesn't matter how many colored people contribute.

Comment: Also, why does it matter if SO's demographics don't match up with overall demographics? What does it really affect? Maybe provide some extra reasoning for that.

Comment: You just said it yourself: "maybe in the outside world it might matter". Well, last time I checked, SO doesn't exist in some isolated bubble. We are part of a global community. I already highlighted why it matters to collect demographic info in my answer. And for the record, it _does_ matter how many "colored" (why tf are you even saying that??) people contribute: diversity is good for our community. I already highlighted bigoted answers in other posts as an example.

Comment: The reason why "tf" I am saying that is two seperate the two demographics. And the thing is, online communities are seperate from the real world.

Comment: "Tracking demographic information is a normal and important part of any community" - no, it absolutely is not. "especially one where the results are so skewed" - this implies that the skew is evidence of bias or wrongdoing. It is not.

Comment: "no, it absolutely is not." - Yes, it is, every other big website does it, and I provided reasoning as to why that is in my post.
"this implies that the skew is evidence of bias or wrongdoing. It is not." - You seem awfully confident about this, do you have any evidence for this claim? I provided evidence to the contrary, you did not. Last time I checked software engineers make decisions on data and evidence, not on what we feel like is right/wrong.

Answer (score -17):

I'm not going to defend SE/SO and say that they doing this purely for the best of intentions, but evidently there's a lot of people that aren't being served well by the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

The company recently released a response to a letter they received about the Code of Conduct.

[Responding to the Lavender Letter and commitments moving forward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354978/responding-to-the-lavender-letter-and-commitments-moving-forward)

The "Lavender Letter" was written and approved by a fairly large amount of people who had gotten bigoted and otherwise hate filled reactions to things they posted. I've had to flag more than a few comments that were less than kind towards others and myself, so I know it happens.

[Dear Stack Exchange: a statement and a letter from your moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334575/dear-stack-exchange-a-statement-and-a-letter-from-your-moderators/334577#334577)

Completely ignoring people's/user's demographics ignores how they may be either underserved, discriminated against, or otherwise shown to be unwelcome (or worse) by this group of sites.

> “If you are neutral in situations of injustice, you have chosen the side of the oppressor”
> – Desmond Tutu
> [...]
> “We must take sides. Neutrality helps the oppressor, never the victim. Silence encourages the tormentor, never the tormented”
> – Elie Wiesel
> [...]
> “Washing one’s hands of the conflict between the powerful and the powerless means to side with the powerful, not to be neutral ”
> – Paulo Freire
> [...]
> “The hottest place in Hell is reserved for those who remain neutral in times of great moral conflict…[an individual] who accepts evil without protesting against it is really cooperating with it”
> – Martin Luther King Jr.

https://organizingchange.org/here-is-how-moral-leaders-approach-neutrality/

> Silence is the Voice of Complicity

https://medium.com/equality-includes-you/silence-is-the-voice-of-complicity-a21525aa2d01

Having SE/SO be transparent how they use the data they collect would definitely be a major benefit, so we know exactly how that data is used. I'm simply using [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) here, rather than any insider knowledge of how the data is actually used, so the other Answers believing the worst could be correct. But I prefer to assume the best, instead of the worst, in people and businesses until I am proven wrong.

And yes, I'm aware of what went down with [Monica Cellio](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel). I'm also aware that making mistakes happens and doesn't necessarily show a systemic or habitual pattern of abuse, even when a single mistake is doubled down on and not corrected.

Now, before you comment, I'm going to ask you to remember the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Also, is your comment based on an knee jerk or emotional reaction, or is it based on something more substantial? I say that because I've seen some rather heated comments on other Answers and the Question itself in this thread, which is part of why I'm posting my own Answer, even though I know it's likely the unpopular opinion and likely to get negative reactions.

Just remember that certain types of negative reaction to this Answer may just prove me right.

Comment: The comments were getting terribly heated and inappropriately political. Comments are not for extended discussion anyway, so this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223197/discussion-on-answer-by-computercarguy-stack-overflow-survey-youre-still-spend) and further commenting on the answer has been disabled. If you want to chat about it, use chat. If you have a counter-argument to present, do so as a new answer.

Answer (score -21):

> We don't care whether those people are black, white, female or Martian, because those personal characteristics are irrelevant.

If we as a community are truly judging content based solely on the content itself, where are all the black, white, female or Martian contributors?

The demographics of those participating in tech (including Stack Overflow) are highly skewed and in no way representative of the population as a whole.

That naturally leads to two questions. Which groups are not participating and why not?

I don't know Stack Overflow's internal policy, but it doesn't seem like too big of a leap to think that the demographics questions are at least in part influenced by the above statements.

> Instead of separating people into demographic groups and attempting to achieve some utopian state of absolute equality, how about improving the onboarding process for new users? Or getting to know your communities better?

I would argue that attempting to find answers to the two questions above addresses both of the problems you mention here in a more significant and lasting way than any UI changes ever will.

Comment: "Which groups are not participating and why not?" My best guess is that's this whole society/culture thing. Everyone is also impacted by the environment. StackOverflow as far as I can see is pretty much neutral and not part of it. I hardly see anything on StackOverflow that would distract from the pure content. Maybe you have seen something?

Comment: I actually agree with this, at least in part. As I pointed out in my answer, some demographics have indicated that they feel particularly unwelcome. At a minimum, we need to find out whether they still feel that way or if the situation has improved. I don't agree that even having a perfectly welcoming community would automatically result in the community exactly reflecting the demographics of the broader culture, though.

Comment: This argument would made a lot more sense if there was any glimpse of asymmetric treatment to different demographic groups. There isn't. It is literally impossible unless said user deliberately came out and identified themselves.

Comment: One female Martian here... Thing is that you cannot force people to do things they don't want to do. When I was in university, there were more female math students than male. But very few of those females were interested in spending days and nights behind the computer. It is not they didn't have opportunity nor skills, nor they were in any way prevented to do so. Simply lack of interest. Me... totally different story.

Comment: And users on SO can be as anonymous as they want. Even some moderators are "very strange creatures". There is literally nobody preventing anyone to participate here. And nobody can tell who anyone else is unless they tell them.

Comment: That disparities exist is not evidence of prejudice. The sources of the disparities are generally other cultural and political factors. I can't do the subject justice in an SO comment, but Thomas Sowell has done so on multiple occasions. [This](https://youtu.be/Y021WAdUlW8) is probably my favorite presentation since it's so data heavy, despite being almost 40 years old. His books are similarly thorough if you'd prefer to read them instead; his [*Discrimination and Disparities*](https://www.amazon.com/Discrimination-Disparities-Thomas-Sowell/dp/154164560X) would obviously be relevant.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I also don't think the demographics could or should exactly reflect the broader culture. But I think the number of women in top tech positions in industry is sitting well below 10%. At least personally, I am curious to know why that is so far from 50%. Whatever the reason may be.

Comment: @jpmc26 I did not say or mean to imply that prejudice is the cause of the disparity. Only that we as a community should be open to trying to figure out why the disparity exists.

Comment: @BernhardBarker The onus is on _you_ to demonstrate that #2 _exists_. You don't get to level an accusation by handwaving.

Comment: @BernhardBarker No, you first identify that there are stairs, and then you start gathering data on its effect. It's statistics 101, you don't get a hypotheses from data. Your situation is even worse than that, you already have the conclusion and is looking for evidence. And finally, you are asking for a proof of innocence. That's not how things work.

Comment: @BernhardBarker This was asked so many times, and the answers have usually consisted of embarassingly handwaving, ideologized lines of ""argumentation"" (like "the white partriarchy is everywhere, so it is here, do you deny that?"), but maybe you can give a sensible response: In how far can #2 be a problem on stackoverflow when someone registers anonymously and asks/answers programming questions, *without providing any information about demographics at all*?

Comment: @BernhardBarker There is basically never a reason to use pronouns here *at all* - not in questions, and not in answers (and very, *very* rarely in comments). The "less concrete" example is **too** un-concrete: It's impossible to derive sensible rules or action patterns from that (beyond "Be nice"). But the answer missed my point: Someone asks "How to do `this` in JavaScript?". Someone answers: "Like that: `code`". Where do cultures, genders, races, ages, trans status, or disability status play **any** role here? They don't. Not at all. (And that's good!!!). So your #2 is not applicable here.

Comment: @BernhardBarker Let's leave out the pronouns (we could be banned for talking about that, for effs sake...). The Q/A that you linked to contains mainly answers that refer to Meta questions. When something in these examples (vaguely) ~"comes across rude", then reasons may be 1. people being rude, 2. ~"cultural differences", 3. (importantly) lack of English skills, and others. (Apart from the fact that there is no reason to be "welcoming" to people who post bad questions and consider all efforts to improve them as ~"toxic"), AFAICS *none* of these examples is strictly related to demographics.

Comment: @Marco13 if you are looking for examples of demographic groups being treated differently, just read the comments on this page. There are plenty of highly upvoted comments saying things like "NY hipsters are ruining StackOverflow", or "some groups just don't have the ability or interest to be programmers". I personally would take this question and the reactions it received as evidence that StackOverflow, or at least MetaSO, has some very strong feelings about non-technical topics.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic My impression may be wrong, maybe I draw conclusions about others from my standpoint, and I try to be careful and not over-generalize this, but I'm **very** sure that for **most** people who participate here on meta (which is only a fraction of the SO user base), the "strong feelings" that you mentioned are present, but they are **not** about the non-technical topics *per se*, but about the fact that these topics are dragged into a site that once was a pure, plain, politics-free Q/A site for programmers, and they think that **these topics just don't belong here**.

Comment: @BernhardBarker 1. Describing history as "systematic oppression" is just wrong. There are practical reasons why society was organized the way it was, not least among them the dominance of hard physical labor as the primary means of production and the implications of child bearing. As labor has become less physically intensive, women have rapidly made inroads to it. Class oppression is just an overly simplistic worldview, no matter the time period under consideration. 2. I do care about how people feel, but caring about how people feel does not require that I give credence to nonsense.

Comment: @BernhardBarker And as far as language goes, the claim is just laughable on its face. Language is not handed top down from some committee. It arises out of large scale consensus in society, a society that has always been composed of approximately half women. There is no practical way men could have unilaterally decided that "he" should be the default.

Comment: @BernhardBarker You're right. It is [full of rude people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342646/1394393) who don't want to act according to their own rules about being nice, and who want to vilify [nice people](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193/14311) to further the false ideology you just espoused. At some point, you can't respond to that kind of terrible behavior by being nice anymore.

Comment: @BernhardBarker There's no empathy in abandoning the truth. There's no empathy in ignoring active injustice here. Me and the people who see things similarly to me have bent over backwards for years to try to abide by the principles SO espoused. We tried our damnedest to to abide by it because we believed it was good. The simple fact is empathy was thrown out the window by others, not us. It's time to be honest about what's happened and stand my ground. Fighting for *everyone* here to be treated fairly and truthfully regardless of their beliefs is the most empathetic thing I can do now.

Comment: @BernhardBarker You at least have to *consider* the possibility that what you describe as "unwelcoming and rude" was *exactly the thing that kept the site working so well*. Of course, you can wear blinders and just *demand* that life should be easy, everybody should get along well, and everybody should be nice and full of love for each other. But one at least has to consider the possibility that the measures that have been established to superficially (!) head towards this goal may be exactly the thing that erodes the foundation of what SO once was: The best Q/A site in the world.

Comment: @BernhardBarker Portraying this as "being rude for the sake of being rude" ist just wrong. This is not about *real* rudeness, but about things that are "perceived to be rude by the receiver". When someone writes good Q/As, there is **no** interaction where "rudeness" could even come into play. When someone writes ~"unsalvageably bad" Q/As, and people clearly discourage this person from doing that, the person may find the (necessary) clarity "rude", but the alternative would be to suggest that ~"we can cope with that", and encourage this person (and others) to just dump their bad Q/As here.

Comment: @BernhardBarker We argue about ~"the definition of 'rude'", and we (and even less the community) will never agree (as this is not about things like "Don't post such crap, you idiot"). But when too many people repeatedly post duplicate/homework questions, and they do so despite the down/closevotes, then comments like "We're not a homework-answersing-machine" or "Do some research", "Format your post" may seem "rude", but may also be more effective at driving away help vampires. Give it a try - try not to be "rude" towards anyone in https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/ ...it's hard

Comment: (An aside: This comment thread has derailed quite a bit. **Iff** we continued, we should do that in chat, but as I said: We could argue endlessly about definitions and perceptions, so I don't think that this would be worthwhile...)

Comment: @BernhardBarker Again, I think that there's not sooo much to gain from further bilateral discussion in this comment thread (specifically under a Q/A that was about a different topic), and the fact that we have to split our comments due to the character limit is a clear indicator of that. But 1. plainly/"intentionally" rude comments will be deleted anyhow, 2. *many* (I'd say most) of the (not rude, but let's say) "blunt" comments are justified, 3. nobody knows exactly how to get rid of help vampires, but "being welcoming to everybody" is **not** the solution. All unrelated to demographics, FWIW

Comment: @jpmc26 `Oh, horror! Someone used the English convention of defaulting to the male pronoun! ` That's no longer true, and native speakers know it. And on those occasions when it is used to represent a neutral gender, I always think of the pronoun "he" as representing a different sex to myself. Can you perhaps explain where I got this strange idea from?

Comment: @Mari-LouA There is not widespread agreement on how to handle the case of an unknown gender of a person. Academic style guides may have settled on something else, but the general populace is all over the place. So yes, it's an old fashioned convention. That still doesn't make it an act of oppression or even rude.

Comment: @jpmc26 it can be rude if a person identifies themself to be nonbinary and tells you that. Would you still insist on using the pronoun "he" for such a person?

Comment: I'd simply move on. When I'm helping people on SO, I'm there to help people, not wade into an ideological war on the state of demographics. I default into whatever fits naturally into the message I am conveying (which for me, happens to be "they/them" unless there are other cues available). I don't need any of this mess getting in the way of helping people.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The entire point here is that the person did not identify themselves. That's why we're talking about a *default*.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm sorry, I have not read every comment because it seems that Bernhard Barkers' comments have been deleted, which might explain why the references to the unidentified person no longer exists.

Comment: "If we as a community are truly judging content based solely on the content itself, where are all the black, white, female or Martian contributors?" I assume they're hanging out with the white reggae artists, the black [curlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curling), the male knitting-club members, and the Earthling ambassadors to Mars. Disparate outcome is not at all clear evidence of an external source of bias or of a societal wrongdoing.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this is a 2 year old post. What brought you to it now?

Comment: "Disparate outcome is not at all clear evidence of an external source of bias or of a societal wrongdoing". Wrong doing, no. But external source of bias absolutely. What other reason could there be? Is there some spell stopping men from knitting? Or maybe, does society view knitting as a hobby for women, and therefore view men who knit as being not "manly". Could that view cause men to choose not to knit? More importantly, how can you even start to ask questions like the former, if you turn a blind eye to underrepresented groups.

Comment: "What other reason could there be [for disparate outcomes on a statistical level]?" Free will? Biology? Why should men and women be expected, on a statistical level, to have identical interests (or abilities), in the absence of an external source of bias? Do you also suppose that, in a truly egalitarian society, it would not be necessary for the Olympics to be gender segregated? If not, *how is that different*? "if you turn a blind eye to underrepresented groups" - this is a strawman.

Comment: It seems you are implying that women and other minorities are biologically less fit for programming than White and Asian men, and that is the root cause of the industry demographics discrepancy? Feel free to correct me if I am misunderstanding you, because I hope that I am...

Comment: As for straw man arguments, the Olympics is a very bad example. When pushed to extreme limits men outperform women at some physical tasks. This is completely unrelated to programming which is neither a physical task nor is it pushing the limits of what a human can achieve. It also completely ignores other underrepresented groups. If the Olympics were entirely made up of a single demographic, wouldn't it be worth looking into why other groups were not participating?